# There's an arrangement of vectors in linear space V over the field K. Is it possible that the field $lin(A)$ is infinitely dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

> Let's take $A = \{α_1, α_2, ...\}$ as an arrangement of vectors in linear space V over the field K. Suppose that dim $lin \{α_i, α_{i+1}, α_{i+2}\} = 2$ for each $i \geq 1$. Is it possible that the field $lin(A)$ is infinitely dimensional?

Vectors $A = \{α_1, α_2, ...\}$ can be seen as a matrix of $2$ linearly independent columns for every $3$ in a row. This can be visualised as:
$$A=\pmatrix{ind&ind&dep&ind&ind&dep&...\\ ind&ind&dep&ind&ind&dep&... \\ ind&ind&dep&ind&ind&dep&...\\ ind&ind&dep&ind&ind&dep&... \\ ...&...&...&...&...&... &...}$$

Then it possible that the field $lin(A)$ is infinitely dimensional.

Can somebody tell me if I think correctly?

Comment: Ok, I will cut them in half then.

Comment: You will  mislead yourself if you label vectors as "independent" or "dependent" - these words apply to sets of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether many of the $\alpha_i$ can be zero.  If infinitely many can be zero, you can have at least one in every three zero and the condition will hold.  If infinitely many are not zero you can have an infinite dimensional space.
If zero vectors are excluded you cannot have an infinite dimensional space.  We are told that we can write $\alpha_3$ as a comibination of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.  Then we can write $\alpha_4$ as a combination of $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$.  What does that tell you?  Continue

Comment: It would mean that the field $lin(A)$ can not be infinitely dimensional. But then my thinking was incorrect. How do you know that every "next" vector is dependent on the previous ones? I mean, in the question it is only told that "dim $lin \{α_i, α_{i+1}, α_{i+2}\} = 2$". Why can't we just "add" an independent vector?

Comment: Because that is true for all $i$.  You were essentially assuming that $i$ has to be $1 \bmod 3$ so you did not get the bridge across your $dep$ columns.  You got a relation between $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ and between $\alpha_4,\alpha_5,\alpha_6$ but missed the one between $\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't think you are right about what the hypothesis implies about each triple of vectors.

Comment: @ancientmathematician:  I have updated it.

Comment: Thanks, I believe it now.  That said, I need a bit of thought to see why the hypothesis of the question leads to the "we are told" sentence. It depends on the "2 dimensional" hypothesis and not just the fact the triple is dependent.

Comment: @RossMillikan- I was going to add a comment about needing to add a separate argument to handle zero vectors, but didn't as I wasn't sure if it was absolutely necessary. But you did it very nicely. +1

Comment: @ancientmathematician- Yeah, I went through the same process about the dimension, where I first thought that $2 \lt 3$ was the only important thing, but later realizing $2 \gt 1$ was also used.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the vector space of real sequences $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Let $e_j$ denote the sequence which has $1$ in the $j$-th place and $0$ elsewhere. Let $f_j=e_j$ when $j\not= 0\mod 3$, and let $f_{3k}=0$.

Then the vectors $f_0, f_1, f_2, \dots$ satisfy the required condition and span an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: Looks like a linearly dependent set to me. Trivially lin. dep., because of the zero vector, but still lin. dep.. I'm guessing that the OP might add the condition that the vectors be non-zero, but as it stands this answer looks right to me.

Comment: Any set containing the zero vector is linearly dependent.